# how to remove only one css file from head tag?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove only one file from all css files which start from `main__`. I have these files in my `head` tag .

```
<link  href="/_next/static/css/640bffeb921775121fc4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/start/dddd/main__dynamic__1.27.171.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I want to remove only one css file

```
 <link href="/start/dddd/main__dynamic__1.27.171.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am doing like this .`item.remove()` remove the file.but how to find css file name. so that I will add check in that .

```
document.querySelectorAll('style,link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach(item => {
                                                                  
       console.log(item)
       //item.remove()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the href attribute string and use startsWith()

```
let hrefAttr = item.getAttribute('href');

let splitHref = hrefAttr.split('/');

if(splitHref[splitHref.length-1].startsWith('__main'))
{
//Your code
}
```